# Implementing Index trait with lifetime

Tags: indexing, rust, overloading, lifetime

I want to overload the indexing operator for this struct :

```
struct Ram<'a> {
    ram: &'a mut [u8]
}

impl<'a> Ram<'a> {
  pub fn new( bytes: &mut[u8]) -> Ram {
    Ram {
        ram: bytes
    }
  }
}
```

... which basically is a "controller" over a byte array. I do it like that because I want to reuse it for byte arrays of different sizes. I understand that the lifetime is here to make sure the "ram" reference is valid throughout the execution. Here's my current index code:

```
use std::ops::{Index};
impl<'a> Index<usize> for Ram<'a> {
    type Output = u8;
    fn index(&self, i: usize) -> &'a u8 {
        &self.ram[i]
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile. Rust says there's an anonymous lifetime definition that conflicts with 'a at the index(...) definition : "error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements".

How am I supposed to implement this? Or am I just plain wrong with my assumptions about lifetimes? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't need to specify the lifetime of the returned reference (note `-> &u8`). [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ed6e98657bf3b54255f85756a985ff54).

The error was because `Index` trait requires lifetime specifier of the object (`&self`) and returned value (`&u8`) to be the same (which is equivalent to require `&self` to live *at least* as long as the returned reference).

For simplicity of coding Rust allows to skip explicit specification of this lifetime, so leaving `&self` and `&u8` is the same as to specify `&'x self` and `&'x u8`. You specified explicitly only one of the references' lifetime, thus confusing the compiler.

```
use std::ops::{Index};
impl<'a> Index<usize> for Ram<'a> {
    type Output = u8;
    fn index(&self, i: usize) -> &u8 {
        &self.ram[i]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut _ram = [0, 1, 2, 3]; 
    let ram_holder = Ram::new(&mut _ram);
    println!("{}", ram_holder[1]);
    // prints: 1
}
```

Comment: Clear answer. I was misled by rustc's error message. Thanks !